# How to MPandroidChart HorizontalBarChart not start zero

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I used MPandroidchart in android.

I want HorizontalBarChart not started Zero.

but HorizontalBarChart BarEntry is input last value and must started zero.

I want to express like a picture. ▼

[image]

Help me....

```
 private ArrayList<IBarDataSet> getDataSet() {
    ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = null;

    ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();
    BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(data, 0); // Jan
    valueSet1.add(v1e1);
    BarEntry v1e2 = new BarEntry(40.000f, 1); // Feb
    valueSet1.add(v1e2);
    BarEntry v1e3 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 2); // Mar
    valueSet1.add(v1e3);
    BarEntry v1e4 = new BarEntry(30.000f, 3); // Apr
    valueSet1.add(v1e4);
    BarEntry v1e5 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 4); // May
    valueSet1.add(v1e5);
    BarEntry v1e6 = new BarEntry(100.000f, 5); // Jun
    valueSet1.add(v1e6);

    IBarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "");

    dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
    return dataSets;
}
```

▲ this data standard will fix it

```
 BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(),getDataSet());

    D_hos_chart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    D_hos_chart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
    D_hos_chart.setPinchZoom(false);
    D_hos_chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

    XAxis xAxis = D_hos_chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setValues(getXAxisValues());
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

    D_hos_chart.setData(data);
    D_hos_chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
    D_hos_chart.invalidate();
```

▲ onCreateView set HorizontalBarChart

[image]

▲ this pic now show, i don`t want start zero..

Comment: I think you need to post more information about it. (Like your code? )

Comment: sorry, i fixed it !

Answer (score 1):

Add below lines in your code:

```
    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setAxisMinimum("yourFloatValue");
```